# PDO Prepared statement returns no Results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameter-passing

```
function db_execute($sql,$db,$array)
{
    require(getcwd() . '/config/config.php');

    if (empty($array))
    { 
        $array = "";
        print "Something wrong";
    }
    $connection = db_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db);
    $q = $connection->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));


    $q ->execute(array($array));

    if(!$q)
    {
        die("Error! " . $connection->errorInfo());
    }

    $result = $q -> fetchAll();

    return $result; 
}

$sql = "SELECT VALUE FROM users WHERE :id = :idnum";
$array = array(':id' => 'USER_ID', ':idnum' => '2');


printFormattedArray($array);
printFormattedArray(db_execute($sql,"user_db",$array));
```

For some reason I can't get any results from this function to return any results. But when I substitute the query with

```
$sql = "SELECT VALUE FROM users WHERE USER_ID = 2";
```

It gives me the required results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `printFormattedArray`?

Comment: Its a function that prints an array in a readable format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have 2 choices.

.1. Refrain from using dynamical identifiers in your queries.
So, go for your second query.

```
$sql   = "SELECT VALUE FROM users WHERE USER_ID = :idnum";
$array = array(':idnum' => '2');
$data  = db_execute($sql, $array);
```

.2. If you need dynamical identifiers, you need a distinct *placeholder* for them as well
So, your code would be like

```
$sql   = "SELECT VALUE FROM users WHERE ?n = ?i";
$data  = db_execute($sql, 'USER_ID', 2);
```

Also,

- **never** connect in the query execution function. Connect once and then use opened connection
- always set your PDO to report mysql errors

add this code after connect

```
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```